# An equivalent of Aware or Awareness for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, time

As per title, I'm looking for a Ubuntu app which is similar to

https://awaremac.com/

or

http://iamfutureproof.com/tools/awareness/

Basically, these are apps that let you know how long you've been at your laptop without a break. They're different from the Pomodoro stuff because they don't try to enforce work intervals of fixed duration, but they either play sounds or show you a timer to make you *aware* of the time spent.

Is there anything like that for Ubuntu? The less invasive, the better. For example, the first one only shows a number followed by `minutes` or `hours` in the taskbar, while the second one simply add(ed) a gong every 1 hr of continous pc usage.

I'd prefer free software, but I'm willing to pay a small fee (say, 10 $) for such a simple tool.

Comment: Probably the simplest software would be google timer.  Just search google for one hour timer and it dings at the end.

Comment: nah, I prefer something which starts automatically when I log in. I don't want to have to remember to start it every time I want to track my usage

Comment: Have you checked the alternative software web site?  Not quite sure of exact name, but google search should bring it up.

Comment: good suggestion! I found this: https://alternativeto.net/software/stretchly/ not exactly what I was looking for, but close enough, I guess.